# Calling external activity in fullscreen mode

Tags: android

I want to persist the immerse mode in my app. However, I am calling an external activity (video player) as shown below:

```
 Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
startActivity(i);
```

The problem is the activity is in full screen mode but after starting the other activity, the full screen mode disappears. How do I keep it so that even after starting a new intent to call an external app, the full screen mode still persist.

Comment: So you are saying you need two styles one is with actionbar or toolbar and as soon as you clicked on the external activity after that all app screens should be in full screen modes

Comment: yes that is exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

In Android by default when you call VideoPlayer It will open in Full Screen Mode. So when you are calling VideoActivity Open activity in full screen mode and start the videoIntent. i:e set the theme of calling activity to fullscreen

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

if you want to set it programatically use below code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Comment: The video player is an external app I have no control over what happens in that activity. This won't work.

Comment: When you are opening video player app, open from full screen activity

Comment: I did but it doesn't persist the full screen mode.